# Longest Common Subsequence

Tags: time-complexity, dynamic-programming, lcs

Consider 2 sequences X[1..m] and Y[1..n]. The memoization algorithm would compute the LCS in time O(m*n). Is there any better algorithm to find out LCS wrt time? I guess memoization done diagonally can give us O(min(m,n)) time complexity.

Comment: Perhaps you mean Longest Common _Substring_? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem

Comment: Nope.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

Comment: Nope its subsequence allright.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gene Myers in 1986 came up with a very nice algorithm for this, described here: [An O(ND) Difference Algorithm and Its Variations](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.4.6927&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

This algorithm takes time proportional to the edit distance between sequences, so it is much faster when the difference is small.  It works by looping over all possible edit distances, starting from 0, until it finds a distance for which an edit script (in some ways the dual of an LCS) can be constructed.  This means that you can "bail out early" if the difference grows above some threshold, which is sometimes convenient.

I believe this algorithm is still used in many `diff` implementations.

Answer (score 1):

If you know a priori an upper bound on the maximum size *k* you care about, you can force the LCS algorithm to exit early by adding an extra check in the inner loop.  This means then when *k << min(m,n)* you can get small running times in spite of the fact you are doing LCS.

Answer (score 0):

yes we could create a better algorithm than Order O(m*n)---
i.e O(min(m,n)). to find a length.....
just compare the diagonal elements.and whenever the increment is done suppose it occured in c[2,2] then increment all the value from c[2,2++] and c[2++,2] by 1..
and proceed till c[m,m]..(suppose m